# regular expression : find all digit in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to get all digits of a string like this :

```
"0" => Groups = "0"
"1 2-3" => Groups = "1", "2", "3"
"45i6" => Groups = "4", "5", "6"
```

I'm using this code :

```
var pattern = @"(\d)";
var m = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(value, pattern);
if(m.Success)
{
    foreach (var gp in m.Groups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(gp);
    }
}
```

Can you help me to get the good pattern please ?

Many thanks

OK, the good code is :

Thanks Daniel

I'm using this code :

```
var pattern = @"(\d)";
var ms = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(value, pattern);
if(ms.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var m in ms)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't stuck on regular expressions, a more straightforward method would be:

```
var digits = someString.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray();
```

Comment: or even: `someString.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray();`

Comment: @soniiic Good call - I always forget about that. ReSharper constantly yells at me for that one.

Answer (score 3):

You want to do `Matches`. You will only have one group with that pattern.

Comment: Thanks Daniel

I'm using this code :

var pattern = @"(\d)";
            var ms = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(value, pattern);
            if(ms.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var m in ms)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(m);
                }
            }